# Output the word in a string with the largest amount of vowels

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, counting, statements

I mostly have the method done but I am confused when it comes to the If statement concerned with storing a variable with the word with the most  amount of vowels, NOTE I am not allowed to use arrays.
below is my code

```
//method for vowels and consonants

public static int Vowelcount(String sentence)
{

    int maxvowelcount =0;
    int minvowelcount =0;
    String vowel="";
    int consonantcount = 0;
    int vowelcount = 0;
    int index = 0;
    String currentword;
    int spacePos;
    int noOfchars = 0;
    int largest = 0 ;
    int smallest = 0 ;

    //gets rid of leading and trailing spaces so as to get the last word
    sentence=sentence.trim() + " ";     

    //assignments
    spacePos=sentence.indexOf(" ");
    currentword = sentence.substring(0, spacePos);

    while (spacePos >-1)// when no spaces are found
    {
        noOfchars=0;
        currentword = sentence.substring(0, spacePos);

        // remove the first word
        sentence = sentence.substring(spacePos+1);

        spacePos=sentence.indexOf(" ");

        // to count the number of vowels in the string 
        for(index = 0; index<currentword.length(); index++)
        {
            if(currentword.charAt(index)=='a' || currentword.charAt(index)=='e' ||
               currentword.charAt(index)=='i' || currentword.charAt(index)=='o' ||
               currentword.charAt(index)=='A' || currentword.charAt(index) == 'E' ||
               currentword.charAt(index) == 'I' || currentword.charAt(index) == 'O' )
            {
                vowelcount++;
            }            
            else
            {
                consonantcount++;
            }       

            //if statement to overwrite currentword with largest/smallest
            if (index == 0)
            {
                minvowelcount = currentword.length();
                maxvowelcount = currentword.length();
            }

            if (vowelcount < minvowelcount)
            {
                minvowelcount = vowelcount;
            }           

            if (vowelcount > maxvowelcount)
            {
                maxvowelcount = vowelcount;
                vowel=currentword;
            }   
        }   
    }   

    //output to show the word with largest amount of vowels
    System.out.println( "word with largest amount of vowels is " + vowel);
    return vowelcount;  
}
```

Comment: Are you not missing the voyel "u" and "y"?

Comment: In how far are you confused? What is the problem with the code? Please gather extra information and then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27692704/edit) your post. And please indent your code properly.

Comment: The area that is causing the most confusion for me is the if statement to overwrite currentword with largest/smallest. I'm sorry about the indentation and the lack of information I am a first year programming student who hasn't done any programming before.

Comment: If you keep editing the code as you go then people aren't going to be able to answer the question ;-)

Comment: I've got no idea what `if (index == 0)
            {
                minvowelcount = currentword.length();
                maxvowelcount = currentword.length();
            }` is for btw.

Answer (score 2):

First, many of the variables you use are redundant. All you need is the max number of vowels and the word. 
Next point is that all your if statements should be outside the for loop. The general structure must be smth like

```
wordWithMaxVowels = "";
maxVowels = 0;
while (there is a word) {
    fetch the word
    vowelCount = 0;
    for (every char in the word) 
    {
        if (char is vowel)
            vowelCount++;
    }
    if (vowelCount > maxVowels)
    {
         vowelCount = maxVowels;
         wordWithMaxVowels = word;
    }
}
// here maxVowels is the maximal number of vowels in a word, wordWithMaxVowels is the word itself;
```

Also note, that it's not any optimal to chop off the first word in the sentence. Try the following:

```
int wordStart = 0;
int wordEnd;
while(true) {
    wordEnd = sentence.indexOf(" ", wordStart);
    if (wordEnd < 0)
        break;
    String word = sentence.substring(wordStart, wordEnd);

    // process the word

    wordStart = wordEnd + 1;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea how to use the say while(there is a word) do I use if(currentword.charAt(index)>='a' && currentword.charAt(index)<='z' || currentword.charAt(index)>='A' && currentword.charAt(index)<='Z')
  {
     
     noOfchars++;
  } 
  
   
 }  
   if(noOfchars == currentword.length())
   {
    wordcount++;
    
    System.out.print( currentword + " " );
   }
   
 }

Comment: See the second snippet.